# The latest version of python module in two linux distributions are different. why?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, alpine-linux

At this moment, 4.7.0 was released 12 hours ago.
I see a list of multidict's versions differently in alpine and ubuntu. Why can't I see 4.7.0 in alpine??

```
$ docker run -i -t alpine:edge /bin/sh

# apk add py3-pip
# pip3 install multidict==
```

`Collecting multidict==
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement multidict== (from versions: 1.0.0a0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0b1, 1.1.0b2, 1.1.0b4, 1.1.0b5, 1.1.0b6, 1.1.0b7, 1.1.0b8, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.3a0, 3.1.3, 3.1.4a1, 3.1.4a2, 3.1.4a3, 3.2.0a3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1a0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0a0, 4.4.0a1, 4.4.0a2, 4.4.0a3, 4.4.0a4, 4.4.0a5, 4.4.0a6, 4.4.0a7, 4.4.0a8, 4.4.0a9, 4.4.0a10, 4.4.0a11, 4.4.0a12, 4.4.0a13, 4.4.0a14, 4.4.0a15, 4.4.0a16, 4.4.0a17, 4.4.0a18, 4.4.0a19, 4.4.0a20, 4.4.0a21, 4.4.0a22, 4.4.0a23, 4.4.0a24, 4.4.0a25, 4.4.0a26, 4.4.0a27, 4.4.0a28, 4.4.0a29, 4.4.0a30, 4.4.0a31, 4.4.0a32, 4.4.0a33, 4.4.0a34, 4.4.0a35, 4.4.0a36, 4.4.0a37, 4.4.0a38, 4.4.0a39, 4.4.0a40, 4.4.0a42, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0a2, 4.6.0a3, 4.6.0, 4.6.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for multidict==`

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash

# apt install python3-pip
# pip3 install multidict==
```

`Collecting multidict==
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement multidict== (from versions: 1.0.0a0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0b1, 1.1.0b2, 1.1.0b4, 1.1.0b5, 1.1.0b6, 1.1.0b7, 1.1.0b8, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.3a0, 3.1.3, 3.1.4a0, 3.1.4a1, 3.1.4a2, 3.1.4a3, 3.2.0a3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1a0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0a0, 4.4.0a1, 4.4.0a2, 4.4.0a3, 4.4.0a4, 4.4.0a5, 4.4.0a6, 4.4.0a7, 4.4.0a8, 4.4.0a9, 4.4.0a10, 4.4.0a11, 4.4.0a12, 4.4.0a13, 4.4.0a14, 4.4.0a15, 4.4.0a16, 4.4.0a17, 4.4.0a18, 4.4.0a19, 4.4.0a20, 4.4.0a21, 4.4.0a22, 4.4.0a23, 4.4.0a24, 4.4.0a25, 4.4.0a26, 4.4.0a27, 4.4.0a28, 4.4.0a29, 4.4.0a30, 4.4.0a31, 4.4.0a32, 4.4.0a33, 4.4.0a34, 4.4.0a35, 4.4.0a36, 4.4.0a37, 4.4.0a38, 4.4.0a39, 4.4.0a40, 4.4.0a42, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0a2, 4.6.0a3, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.0)
No matching distribution found for multidict==`

---

updated

for now, you can see like below. why version 4.7.0 is not found in alpine?

## alpine

`Collecting multidict==
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement multidict== (from versions: 1.0.0a0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0b1, 1.1.0b2, 1.1.0b4, 1.1.0b5, 1.1.0b6, 1.1.0b7, 1.1.0b8, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.3a0, 3.1.3, 3.1.4a1, 3.1.4a2, 3.1.4a3, 3.2.0a3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1a0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0a0, 4.4.0a1, 4.4.0a2, 4.4.0a3, 4.4.0a4, 4.4.0a5, 4.4.0a6, 4.4.0a7, 4.4.0a8, 4.4.0a9, 4.4.0a10, 4.4.0a11, 4.4.0a12, 4.4.0a13, 4.4.0a14, 4.4.0a15, 4.4.0a16, 4.4.0a17, 4.4.0a18, 4.4.0a19, 4.4.0a20, 4.4.0a21, 4.4.0a22, 4.4.0a23, 4.4.0a24, 4.4.0a25, 4.4.0a26, 4.4.0a27, 4.4.0a28, 4.4.0a29, 4.4.0a30, 4.4.0a31, 4.4.0a32, 4.4.0a33, 4.4.0a34, 4.4.0a35, 4.4.0a36, 4.4.0a37, 4.4.0a38, 4.4.0a39, 4.4.0a40, 4.4.0a42, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0a2, 4.6.0a3, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for multidict==`

## Ubuntu

`Collecting multidict==
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement multidict== (from versions: 1.0.0a0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0b1, 1.1.0b2, 1.1.0b4, 1.1.0b5, 1.1.0b6, 1.1.0b7, 1.1.0b8, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.3a0, 3.1.3, 3.1.4a0, 3.1.4a1, 3.1.4a2, 3.1.4a3, 3.2.0a3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1a0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0a0, 4.4.0a1, 4.4.0a2, 4.4.0a3, 4.4.0a4, 4.4.0a5, 4.4.0a6, 4.4.0a7, 4.4.0a8, 4.4.0a9, 4.4.0a10, 4.4.0a11, 4.4.0a12, 4.4.0a13, 4.4.0a14, 4.4.0a15, 4.4.0a16, 4.4.0a17, 4.4.0a18, 4.4.0a19, 4.4.0a20, 4.4.0a21, 4.4.0a22, 4.4.0a23, 4.4.0a24, 4.4.0a25, 4.4.0a26, 4.4.0a27, 4.4.0a28, 4.4.0a29, 4.4.0a30, 4.4.0a31, 4.4.0a32, 4.4.0a33, 4.4.0a34, 4.4.0a35, 4.4.0a36, 4.4.0a37, 4.4.0a38, 4.4.0a39, 4.4.0a40, 4.4.0a42, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0a2, 4.6.0a3, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.0, 4.7.1)
No matching distribution found for multidict==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because for the version *4.7.0*, there is no *source distribution* available on *PyPI*. See the [list of distributions for *multidict 4.7.0*](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/4.7.0/#files). Then compare this to the [list of distributions for *multidict 4.7.1*](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/4.7.1/#files), this one has a `multidict-4.7.1.tar.gz`.

Most likely none of the *Python wheel built distribution* available are suitable for *Alpine Linux* (something about the different *libc* maybe, I am not sure), so it falls back to the source distribution instead. But when there is no source distribution then this specific version just can't be built and installed at all.

See the ["Platform Detection for Installers" section of PEP 513 -- A Platform Tag for Portable Linux Built Distributions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#platform-detection-for-installers):

> We know of four main sources of potential incompatibility that are likely to arise in practice:
>
> - [...]
> - A linux distribution that does not use glibc (e.g. Alpine Linux, which is based on musl libc, or Android)